# Реализовать функции в интерфейсе

Tags: java, многопоточность, интерфейс

Есть интерфейс `ContactStore`:

```
public interface ContactStore {
   List<Contact> all();
   List<Contact> search(String term);
   void add(Contact contact);
   boolean remove(long id);
}
```

Требуется что-бы я создал дочерние классы  `Runnable` интерфейса, в которых будут реализованы эти функции. Нужно для программы `Contact list` , для того что-бы было можно без проблем работать с данными из разных баз.

Comment: и в чем, собственно, проблема и вопрос?

Comment: проблема в том что я не знаю как все это реализовать а вопрос в том поможет ли мне кто-нибудь это сделать

Comment: Вы не умеете наследоваться от интерфейсов и реализовывать их абстрактные методы? Тогда вам на курсы по `Java - Базовый`

Comment: Вы просто вопрос не поняли, может кто нибудь друогой поймет и поможет мне.

Comment: и на Java - Базовый у меня нет времени потому-что завтра надо здавать, поэтому спрашиваю тут

Comment: Ну то есть за вас надо написать логику..... понятно. А вы пробовали что-то сами написать?

Comment: я уже написал целый код но на этом месте я застрял

Comment: Stack Overflow не предназначен для выполнения учебных заданий другими участниками вместо вас. Если хотите стать программистом - учитесь самостоятельно. Если вы не учитесь - вы не хотите стать программистом.

Comment: Другими словами: `Требуется что-бы я создал` - раз требуется, так создайте. В вышеприведенном коде этих классов нет.

Comment: Давайте вы сюда выложите текст вашего задания целиком, как он есть. Делать его за вас вряд ли кто-то будет (сообщество несколько нетерпимо к просьбам сделать за вас домашку), но могут в комментариях что-то посоветовать.

Comment: Я учусь по примерам, нужен какой нибудь пример что-бы понять. и я тут новый так что не знаю для чего конкретно преднозначен stackoverflow.com. думал тут помагают друг другу.

Comment: Задание не на русском язике а переводить его целеком будет очен сложно потому-что  болшое задание 2 страници буквь. да я вижу что никому не понравился мой вопрос , могу извинится и удалить если нужно....

Comment: @Zeroone верно, тут помогают разбираться и находить решения, но только когда автор вопроса сам прикладывает к этому усилия. Мы все тут в чём-то новички и тоже задаем вопросы, когда сами бьемся и не можем найти решения. Но по вашему вопросу непохоже, чтобы вы пытались что-то решить самостоятельно. Здесь же просто формулировка задания. Если вы уже что-то написали, тогда выложите код и расскажите, что именно не работает, какой результат есть, какой должен быть.

Comment: @Zeroone но мы не сможем заменить вам учебник. Если вы не понимаете, что вообще означает "реализовать интерфейс" или как это правильно сделать - берите любой учебник, читайте и выполняйте задания. Это будет лучшее, что вы можете сделать для своего обучения в данный момент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class RunnabaleContacts implements Runnable, ContactStore 
{
     //IDE сама предложит реализовать методы интерфейсов
}
```

Comment: Нужно  реализоват каждый метод  по отделности

Comment: Не не не.. судя по комментарию ТС - это неправильно. Потому, что я именно об этом говорил, а мне сказали что я не понял вопрос........ ТС'у надо чтоб за него сделали код))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Юрий приводит самый удобный и надёжный способ создать шаблоны методов - обозначить имплементируемые интерфейсы и предоставить среде разработки создать эти шаблоны. Но автор даже не попробовал этот метод, поэтому и не знает, что это именно то, что сработает.

Comment: @NickVolynkin то, что надо `implements someInterfaces` у классов написать я знаю... я как раз об этом....но автору надо реализовать саму логику, а не просто их имплементировать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну, я просто интерпретировал вопрос в ключе "я знаю какой код будет в методах, но не знаю каков синтаксис описания множественной реализации интерфейсов". Вот на этот вопрос я и ответил)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я тоже так подумал, поэтому я предложил автору почитать java - базовый))  ибо если вопрос был бы в этом - то это вообще позор(((  особенно для java программиста

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но почему же сразу позор? Я ещё помню времена, когда вовсю кописастил код с интерфейсами и заставлял его работать совсем не понимая что эти интерфейсы значат. А когда решил таки разобраться - дело у меня не сразу пошло. Интерфейсы - довольно заумная штука для непосвящённых)